# MGF and Compound Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

I have $N_{t}$ governed by a [Compound Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution#Definition)$(t\lambda$) distribution with expected value $t\lambda$ and a sequence of $X_{i}$ where each $X_{i}$ is independent of $N_{t}$. If $Y = \sum^{N_{t}}_{i=1} X_{i}$, how can I find the mgf and first moment of $Y$?

I am used to the continuous case where I can integrate and differentiate, but I don't think I can apply that here due to the discrete nature of this distribution.

Answer (score 5):

First off, saying "$N_t$ governed by a compound $\mathsf{Poisson}(t\lambda)$ distribution" and defining $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{N_t} X_i$ is a bit confusing - I believe what you meant is that there is a given value $\lambda>0$, and for each $t>0$ you define the random variable
$$
Y_t = \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} X_i,
$$
so that $\{Y_t : t>0\}$ is a stochastic process - that is, a collection of random variables indexed on time - where $Y_t$ has compound $\mathsf{Poisson}(t\lambda)$ distribution.

In this case, assuming the $X_i$ are i.i.d., the expected value of $Y_t$ can be computed using the law of total expectation:
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y_t] &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y_t\mid N_t]]\\
&= \mathbb E[N_t\mathbb E[X_1]]\\
&= \mathbb E[N_t]\mathbb E[X_1]\\
&= t\lambda\mathbb E[X_1].
\end{align}
The moment-generating function of $Y_t$ is given by
\begin{align}
M_{Y_t}(\theta) :&= \mathbb E[\exp(\theta Y_t)]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\theta\sum_{i=1}^{N_t} X_i\right) \right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\theta X_i\right)^{N_t}\mid N_t \right]\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[M_{X_1}(\theta)^{N_t} \right].
\end{align}
Recall that for a random variable $W$ with $\mathsf{Poisson}(\mu)$ distribution, the probability-generating function of $W$ is
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[s^W] &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(W=k)\cdot s^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^k}{k!}\cdot s^k\\
&= e^{-\mu}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(s\mu)^k}{k!}\\
&= e^{-\mu} e^{s\mu}\\
&= e^{\mu(s - 1)}.
\end{align}
It follows then that the probability-generating function of $N_t$ is $e^{t\lambda(s -1)}$, and so
$$
M_{Y_t}(\theta) = e^{t\lambda (M_{X_1}(\theta)-1)}.
$$
For example, if $X_1\sim\mathsf{Ber}(p)$ then
$$
M_{X_1}(\theta) = e^{\theta\cdot 0}(1-p) + e^{\theta\cdot 1}p = 1 - p + pe^{\theta},
$$
in which case
\begin{align}
M_{Y_t}(\theta) &= e^{t\lambda p\left(1-e^\theta\right)}.
\end{align}

Comment: In order to make the equality $\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\theta X_i\right)^{N_t}\mid N_t \right]\right] =\mathbb E\left[M_{X_1}(\theta)^{N_t} \right]$ rigorous, we need to prove that $\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\theta X_i\right)^{N_t}\mid N_t \right]=\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\theta X_i\right)\mid N_t \right]^{N_t}$ almost surely. **Proof:** Clearly, these two random variables are $N_t$-measurable. Secondly, one can check that their integrals over any $A\in \sigma(N_t)$ are equal. By the almost sure uniqueness of conditional expectation, they are equal almost surely.