# Prove the existence of $g$ such that $\mathbb E (e^{aX_t} ) = e^{g(a) t}$ for a Compound Poisson Process $X_t$

Tags: probability-theory, functions, continuity, stochastic-processes, independence

I have been studying a course on Stochastic Processes and recently encountered the following result with the proof listed as an exercise.

> Let $X_t$ be a Compound Poisson Process defined by the sum of iid random variables $(Y_n)$ independent of $N$, written explicitly as:
> $$ X_t := Y_1 + Y_2 + \cdots + Y_{N_t}$$
> where $N$ is a Poisson Process.
>
> Show that there exists a function $g(a)$ such that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $$\mathbb E (e^{aX_t} ) = e^{g(a) t}$$

By the independence of $(Y_n)$, we can write the following:
$$\mathbb E (e^{a X_t}) = \mathbb E (e^{aY_1}e^{aY_2} \cdots e^{aY_{N_t}}) = \mathbb E (e^{aY_1}) \mathbb E (e^{aY_2}) \cdots \mathbb E (e^{aY_{N_t}})$$

**Observation:** this is the product of the MGFs for each of the $Y_i$, however, as the distribution of $Y_i$ is unknown but iid, this means that all the MGFs will be the same for each $Y_i$. Which simplifies the above to:

$$\mathbb E (e^{a X_t}) = \mathbb E (e^{aY_1})^{N_t}$$

Now I believe there is some merit to the next approach that I take, but I don't believe that I am formalising it correctly or perhaps applying the lemma in the wrong way. But first, observe the lemma itself:

> **Lemma:** if $f$ is a continuous function such that $f(t+s) = f(t)f(s)$, then either $f =0$ or $f = e^{bt}$ for some constant $b$.

If I define the set $A := \{ Y_1, \space \cdots , \space Y_{N_t} \}$, then we can define the function $f$ with domain $A$ as $f(Y) = \mathbb{E}(e^{a Y})$. This function satisfies the second part of the **Lemma**, however, I am unsure about continuity.

---

Is this approach to the problem along the right lines, or should I try something else?

Comment: Of course, $g(a) =\frac{\ln \mathbb E[e^{aX_t}]}{t}$, so try and prove that the right hand side is independent of $t$. Maybe try looking first at $t=1$ and $t=2$, then look at integer $t$, and rational $t$ and so on. I'm still not clear on the definition of the Compound Poisson process : is $N$ itself a Poisson process? So that you have $N \equiv \{N_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ which is taking values in the integers, and then the definition of $X_t$ makes sense.

Comment: Yes, $N$ is a Poisson Process. I will edit the question to make that explicit @SarveshRavichandranIyer

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point about showing that the right-hand side is independent of $t$ though as the $X_t$ inside the expectation means that there will be a dependency on $t$?  @SarveshRavichandranIyer

Comment: I should have been more clear. I mean the following : prove that the quantity $\frac{\ln \mathbb E[e^{aX_t}]}{t}$ is, in fact, independent of $t$. Once you do that, you can define $g(a)$ as that quantity and be done. For example, how would you prove that $\frac{\ln \mathbb E[e^{aX_1}]}{1} = \frac{\ln \mathbb E[e^{aX_2}]}{2}$? Try proving this.

Comment: That would reduce to verifying that $(e^{aX_1})^2 = e^{aX_2}$? @SarveshRavichandranIyer

Comment: That won't be true, unfortunately. But note that $X_2 = (X_2-X_1)+X_1$, and $X_2-X_1$ is independent of $X_1$ and has the same distribution as $X_1$. Try and use this. (+1)

Comment: So applying this to the above and simplifying, we are looking to prove that $E(e^{aX_1}) = E(e^{a(X_2 - X_1)})$? Although actually that is just trivial because it reduces further down to $E(e^{aY_1}) = E(e^{aY_2})$ which is clearly true by the iid nature of each $Y_i$

Comment: $$\begin{aligned}E[e^{aX_t}]&=E[E[e^{a(Y_1+...+Y_n)}]|_{N_t=n}]\\
&=E[(E[e^{a Y_1}])^{N_t}]\\
&=\sum_n (E[e^{a Y_1}])^n\frac{(\lambda t)^ne^{-\lambda t}}{n!}\\
&=e^{-\lambda t}e^{E[e^{a Y_1}]\lambda t}\\
&=e^{\lambda t(E[e^{a Y_1}]-1)}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Feel free to post this as an answer. Could you also clarify why your second equality doesn't keep the conditioning and raise to the power of $n$ rather than $N_t$ @Snoop

Comment: @FD_bfa it is due to the independence of $N$ from $(Y_n)_{n}$. This question and this answer have appeared many times here, [e.g.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3912794/mgf-and-compound-poisson-distribution). In my opinion, a good novel answer here would not use this approach (as you have also asked).